# Date from a string iOS

Tags: ios4

My dateString is like the following: Tue, 08 Nov 2011 08:42:35
I tried to parse it using NSDateFormatter and following is the code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Tue, 08 Nov 2011 08:42:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM YYYY'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *publishedDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

But it always returns nil to publishDate.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your date format string doesn't match your date string.  The one you provided (`"EEE, d MMM YYYY'T'HH:mm:ss"`) would match dates that look like `"Tue, 8 Nov 2011T23:14:42"`.  That's not what it should be.

```
Tue, 08 Nov 2011 08:42:35
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: @user1036201 if this has satisfactorily answered your question, you can mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark underneath the up/down arrows. :)